# How to reverse the z-index of child components? (push animation in React)

Tags: javascript, animation, reactjs

So, I have a push/pop animation I'm working on. The pop animation works just fine because of order in which `<CSSTransitionGroup>` appends its children.

However for the push animation, I want to views to stack the opposite way in terms of the z-index. So I set `z-index:1` for the `push-enter` animation and that works except when I layer multiple animations on top.

Check out my example: http://codepen.io/ccorcos/pen/MwXXaz
Press the `inc` button a quickly. Then change the `transitionName` to "pop" to see the other animation.

This is a work-around but its not very elegant:

```
.transition-group > .box:nth-child(0) {
  z-index: 4;
}

.transition-group > .box:nth-child(1) {
  z-index: 3;
}

.transition-group > .box:nth-child(2) {
  z-index: 2;
}

.transition-group > .box:nth-child(3) {
  z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: On the `push` animation, you want the entering box to appear on top of the previously box which is about to leave?

Comment: And similarly on `pop` animation, you want another entering box to appear on top of the previous box which is leaving? Basically in both the cases, the appearing box should always be on top if I have been able to understand it correctly.

Comment: imagine it like a stack of cards. on push, the appearing element should stack on top. when popping, the appearing element should be under the leaving element. These animations are just the reverse of each other, much like iOS push/pop for their UINavigationController.

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong but try this:

- Add **`z-index: 1;`** into the CSS rules **`.push-enter`** & **`.pop-enter`**.
- Add **`z-index: -1;`** into the CSS rules **`.push-leave`** & **`.pop-leave`**.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The problem with this is: now try pressing the button multiple times quickly. The animation looks messed up doesnt it?

Comment: lets try to solve them one by one. by the way, do you mind a little bit of JavaScript here? it seems like dynamic manipulation of `z-index` here based on the type of animation we want to trigger?

Comment: @Chet: so with current setting of `z-index: 1;` on `.push-enter` & `z-index: -1;` on `.push-leave`, does it produces your desired result?

Comment: I'd like to use only CSS. The pop animation works due to the order in which React CSSTransitionGroup appends new elements: http://codepen.io/ccorcos/pen/MwBOvw

Comment: However, the push animation should have the opposite layering which isnt happening here: http://codepen.io/ccorcos/pen/qdyVXj

Comment: your multiple clicks don't work anyway right, if clicked fast?

Comment: the animations wont work the right way... If I use the z index trick, then it works for the first push, but when I click several times, then you'll see it gets messed up: http://codepen.io/ccorcos/pen/aOjVEJ

Comment: can you quickly take a look at [this](http://codepen.io/tah_med/pen/RPBLdZ?editors=011) please? I have slowed the animation down a little bit to observe.

Comment: Weird. This is closer though. On the second click, the second square is in the back rather than the middle though...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83581/discussion-between-tahir-ahmed-and-chet).